# I'm trying to equalize the height of the cards using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, frontend

I'm trying to make something like this:

[image]

But i have no idea how to equalize the heights of the first and second column.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! Would you mind adding your attempt to your post via the snippet editor to allow folks to trouble shoot and respond with solutions easier to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with **CSS Grid**.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 12.5%);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-row-gap: 7px;
}

.box_1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;
    grid-row: span 2;
}

.box_2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;
}

.box_3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "box_1"></div>
    <div class = "box_2"></div>
    <div class = "box_3"></div>
</div>
```